# Column total value at the end of a dynamic table using VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

**strong text**[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM4jC.png)
[image]

I want to get the total of the columns "Value" & "Quantity" which is in a dynamic table (in which number of rows will be different each time) at the end of the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select a cell in your table the *Table Design* menu will appear on the Ribbon. In it is a checkbox for *Total Row*. Check it.

This will add a total row to your table. In my test it contained a total only for the last column on the left. However, you can use that same formula, modified for the appropriate column name, in other columns as well. The row will automatically stay at the bottom of the table when you add rows.

To add rows at the bottom manually, place the cursor in the last cell on the right (not in the totals row but above it) and hit Tab. You can also select any cell in the table and click *Insert Table Row* either above or below the clicked cell.

All of the above works for a true table. You exhibit doesn't look like a true table. If it isn't, please consider one of two options. Either replace the table you already have with what is called a "Table" in Excel and enjoy the advantages that offers, or modify your question to clarify that your question applies to a list of data which are ***not*** in a table.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
dim TotalValue as Long
dim i, value as integer

value = 1 'use the column number of Value
i = 1

Do until isempty(workbooks("yourworkbook.xlsm").worksheets(1).cells(i,Value)) = True
  Totalvalue = TotalValue + workbooks(yourworkbook.xlsm).worksheets(1).cells(i,Value)
  i = i + 1
Loop

i = i + 1
(workbooks(yourworkbook.xlsm).worksheets(1).cells(i,Value).value = TotalValue
```

Then do the same with Quantity column